# Ошибка при создании объекта из interface

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

Разрабатывал приложение на Angular и получил ошибку

> "Property 'post' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in
> the constructor."

подскажите, как ее исправить.

app.components.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export interface Post {
  title: string;
  text: string;
  id?: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  posts: Post[] = [
    { title: 'Wanna lear Angular...', text: 'Im learning smth', id: 1 },
    { title: 'lorem2', text: 'lksdnlfsd', id: 2 },
  ];
}
```

post.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../app.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.scss'],
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() post: Post;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130896/discussion-on-question-by-m4ch1n3ry------interface).

Answer (score 0):

Добавь восклицательный знак сразу после слова `post`: `@Input() post!: Post;`.

Таким образом, ты указываешь TypeScript, что данное поле проинициализировано (извне, например через декоратор).